# REER ULC vs. REER PPP

Tags: exchange

Can someone give an example and an exponation of how a currency may be *undervalued* when considering its REER (real exchange rate) in PPP terms, but *overvalued* when looking at the REER based on ULC (unit labor costs) in manufacturing.

So far, I have gone back to definitions:

$$REER_{ULC} \ overvalued = S \times \dfrac{w^*}{w} \\ REER_{CPI} \ undervalued = S \times \dfrac{P^*}{P}$$

Where $S$ is the exchange rate, $w^*$ wages in manufacturing sector abroad, $w$ wages in manufacturing sector at home, $P^*$ the level of prices abroad, $P$ level of prices at home.

To be overvalued we need that $REER_{ULC} < 1$. To make things simple lets say that $S = 1$. Then it should imply that $w>w^*$. For the undervaluation of the REER in PPP terms we need that $REER_{CPI}>1$. Which implies that $P < P^*$.

That being said I thought we could take a developed country as an example, where wages in the manufacturing sector would be higher. But however I don't see how we could get $P<P^*$ even if we take into account a tradable and non-tradable sector. Would it be because the prices in the non-tradable sector at home are lower than the one abroad so that they somehow compensate the overall level of prices? This would really go against my intuition.